# How to make SplashScreen wait for a condition met in the ViewModel of my main activity?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

My `MainActivity` begins as follow :

```kotlin
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        installSplashScreen().setKeepOnScreenCondition {appViewModel.isReady}
        
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContent {

            val appViewModel: AppViewModel = viewModel(factory = AppViewModel.factory)

            val uiState by appViewModel.uiStateFlow.collectAsState()
```

Of course, when `appViewModel.isReady` is used, it is unknown because `appViewModel` is declared later (after the `setContent`).

I can't declare `appViewModel` above `setContent` (`@Composable invocations can only happen within the context of @Composable function`). `installSplashScreen()...` must be declared before `super.onCreate` according to the documentation.

So : how could I make the splash screen wait for `isReady` variable set to true in the `appViewModel` ?

Thank you.

EDIT :

Here is what I finally did :

```kotlin
val appViewModel by viewModels<AppViewModel> { AppViewModel.factory }

        installSplashScreen().setKeepOnScreenCondition { appViewModel.isLoading }

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
```

Comment: You can inject the ViewModel into both your activity and root composable

Comment: @Philio, some guidelines on how to proceed would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: it's essentially the same principle as a shared VM between an activity and a fragment as in the docs https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/ViewModel

Comment: @Philio : FYI I updated OP with what I was looking for.